# What bitcoin wallets supports SegWit?

Tags: wallet, segregated-witness

It's more than a week since SegWit activation, and still there seems to be almost no wallet out there supporting SegWit?

Well, I've heard Trezor supporting it, but no ... I don't want to buy a hardware device.

Bitcoin Core and BTC1 supports it from the command line ... but no, I'm not interested in running a full node at the moment (again, that would require me to buy hardware - I probably should set up a full node, but that's probably not happening this month).

I had electrum installed, and it is supposed to support SegWit - but no, can't seem to get it to work. Even tried downloading the bleeding edge version from git, but no ... no segwit, and it was crashing with error messages all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of wallers which supporting a SegWit

[bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_adoption](https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_adoption/)

Comment: I don't think it's much useful - like, my wallet (Electrum) has been "ready" on that list since long before SegWit got activated, but I still can't see any support for SegWit for regular end users.